# Problema con los reportes con imagenes en java

Tags: jasper-reports

Hice un reporte llamado Socios.jrxml que llama así a la imagen:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["F:\\Datos\\Desktop\\ProyectoAC\\src\\imagenes\\icono.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

Lo llamo desde un *menu item* así:

```
      Conectar con = new Conectar();
      Connection conexion = con.conexion();
      try {
        String rutaReporte = System.getProperty("user.dir") +    "/src/Informes/Socios.jasper";
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaReporte);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conexion);
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print, false);
        view.setVisible(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error al generar el reporte -> " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Y me sale este error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Error al generar el reporte -> Byte data not found at: F:\Datos\Desktop\ProyectoAC\src\imagenes\icono.png.
```

Esto me pasa cuando cambio de ordenador, me coge la ruta del ordenador en el que lo hice. Y aunque cambie la ruta de la imagen me sigue saliendo ese error  es como si no se me actualizara el reporte porque aunque borre la imagen en el Socios.jrxml me sigue dando error con esa ruta. En el ordenador en el que lo hice si que funciona porque la ruta coincide pero en cualquier otro no.

Agradezco una solución

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una carpeta, con tu `report` y la `imagen`.

Una vez tienes creada la carpeta para la llamada de la imagen lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
 <image>
    <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="220" height="35" uuid="bec3aafd-0381-4bfd-b2b6-2fe7dd4cf37b"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["repo:logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Utilizando esto

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["repo:logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

Independientemente del equipo que tengamos tenemos acceso a ella ya que siempre la encontrará.

Comment: Sii pero no me actualiza los informes, es decir, da igual lo que yo cambie en el jrxml, saca informes anteriores, es como si no actualizara el .jasper o algo

Comment: ¿Que editor utilizas? Debes modificar el informe y compilar para que refresque y genere de nuevo el jasper, o bien hacer la llamada en tu código java al .jrxml

Comment: Uso ireports, acabo de hacerlo como me dijiste y no me reconoce el icono. Hice clean and build  Error filling print... Byte data not found at : Informes:icono.png 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : Informes:icono.png      at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:324)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.RenderableUtil.getRenderable(RenderableUtil.java:121)

Comment: Lo tienes subido al servidor o estás en tu local?

Comment: Estoy en local conectado a mi base de datos

Comment: Ese error corresponde a que no encuentra la imagen, ya que la opción que le he dado es para que la imagen se visualice si está subido al servidor. Creo que el problema es de compilación del jasper

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás utilizando una [ruta absoluta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_absoluta) al archivo de la imagen, en la definición de tu reporte. En tiempo de corrida, jasper busca la imagen en la ruta exacta, debido a que es absoluta.

La solución es utilizar una [ruta relativa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_relativa)<sup>1</sup>.

Supongo, de lo que puedo ver, que tienes una estructura de carpetas como esta:

```
RutaBase
  src
    Imagenes
      icono.png
    Informes
      Socios.jasper
```

Donde `Base` puede variar entre una máquina y otra.

En el jrxml, Define tu imagen de esta forma:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA["../imagenes/icono.png"]]></imageExpression>
```

Es necesario, luego de este cambio, que compiles el reporte y pases el `Socios.jasper` a la computadora donde estás haciendo las pruebas.

---

<sup>1</sup>: La ruta es *relativa* a la ubicación del archivo `jasper`.

Comment: Lo hice así en el xml <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Informes\\icono.png"]]></imageExpression>. Compile el jasper y hice clean and build y funcionaba perfecto. Sin embargo al cambiar de computadora me sigue cogiendo otra ruta que no sé de donde: C:\Users\David\Desktop\proyectoAC\src\Informes\icono.png. Esa es la ruta donde lo tengo ubicado en el otro pc pero yo no la he puesto en ningún sitio nosé porque coge esa

Comment: Si sigue tomando la otra ruta es porque el compilado no está actualizado. No tiene de otra. Verifica la fecha y hora del .jasper en tu equipo de desarrollo. ¿es congruente?, OK, Luego en la otra PC, ¿es la misma? ¿estás seguro que no hay otra copia del `.jasper` por allí?

Comment: Como se compilaría de nuevo el .jasper?, porque quizás es que no lo esté haciendo bien

Comment: en iReport, selecciona el reporte en el _Report inspector_, botón derecho del ratón y _Compile report_.

Comment: Si no hay problemas, en la consola verás algo como:   `Compiling to file... C:\x\y\z\miReporte.jasper`... Compilation running time: 2,021

Comment: Nada lo hago miro la hora es correcta pero mi sigue cogiendo otra ruta. De hecho al arrancar el proyecto y darle al menu item que abre el reporte, me da la ruta que no es, y vuelvo al xml y es porque la ha cambiado el programa sola y está la ruta que es incorrecta

Comment: Intenta algo, borra el .jasper. ¿qué pasa?

Comment: Lo borro pongo la ruta correcta en el jrxml. Compilo y cuando intento hacer preview me sale la ruta que no es a pesar de que en el xml ahora esta bien

Comment: Si lo borras, en el equipo que no es de desarrollo, y no pasas uno nuevo, qué pasa?

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Que borre el .jasper y no haga uno nuevo?

Comment: No, el `.jasper` es un binario. El fuente es el `.jrxml`. Lo que quiero es que te asegures que tu sistema está utilizando el archivo que tu crees que está utilizando. También es posible derivar un `jrxml` a partir de un `jasper` y no se si tu sistema tiene codificado algo así. En tiempo de corrida solo se va a utilizar el `jasper`, que es el compilado, para generar el reporte.